# Error when updating data into a database

Tags: php, database, button, post, get

I'm trying to create an admin page where the admin must approve a user registration before the user logs in.I'm trying to show in this page all the users which have been registered but still waiting for admin approval for log in.So I want to create a button close to each unconfirmed user with the value"Yes" to give the admin the possibility to approve his account.If "Yes" button is set by the admin the user should be approved so the `approval` field which is stored in my database should be updated to 1.This is the idea.When executing the code the buttons are displayed but no update is made for the field `approval`!

Also the buttons are displayed but are not functional.Can someone help me to make the "Yes" buttons functional?
This is my code:

```html
<html >
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )
   print("Could not connect");
if(isset($_POST['yes'])){

     $id = intval($_POST['id']);
$update_query= "UPDATE login SET `approval`=1 WHERE `id` = '".$id."'";
mysql_query($update_query,$database);
 }

$query = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `admin` =0";
 if(!($result=mysql_query($query,$database)))
{
    print("Could not execute query");
    die (mysql_error());//ose error
} else
  while($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {

 $firstname=$query_row['firstname'];
$lastname=$query_row['lastname'];
$username=$query_row['username'];
$password=$query_row['password'];
$email=$query_row['email'];
$cv=$query_row['cv'];
$id=$query_row['id'];

if($query_row['approval']==0){
  echo "this user is waiting for you approval";
echo $firstname.'   '.$lastname.'  has this cv:'.$cv.'<br />
Do you want to approve his account?
<form action="admin.php" method="post">
<input  type="text" style="display: none;" value="$id" name="id">
<input  type="submit" value="yes" name="yes">
</form>
<br/>';
}
}
mysql_close($database);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone helping me with this updating?Thanks in advance!

Comment: show the HTML code also, please

Comment: This is all my code for this admin page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the button to be

```
<form action="admin.php" method="post"><input type="submit" value="'.$id.'" name="id"></form><br />';
```

So that the whole echo will be

```
echo $firstname.' '.$lastname.' has this cv:'.$cv.'<br /> Do you want to approve his account? <form action="admin.php" method="post"><input type="submit" value="'.$id.'" name="id"></form><br />';
```

The `name` of the form element is what you should expect to be the key in the `$_POST` array, and the `value` is what you should expect to be the value of `$_POST['id']`

Also, you should use `$_POST` not `$_GET` as you have specified the form method to be `post`

Comment: totally not working like this

Comment: What is the error you get now?

Comment: That should be the whole echo command, including the button.

Comment: Ok the buttons are displayed but the `approval ` field in the dtabase isn't updated

Comment: I think i have a prob with this part of code :if(isset($_POST['yes'])){
     $id = intval($_POST['id']);
$update_query= "UPDATE login SET `approval`=1 WHERE `id` = '".$id."'";
 }

Comment: This is because you are NOT actually running the update query, you are only constructing it, you need to at least write this line

Comment: mysql_query($update_query,$database);

Comment: under $update_query= "UPDATE login SET `approval`=1 WHERE `id` = '".$id."'";

Comment: Just check if(isset($_POST['id'])) instead of if(isset($_POST['yes']))

Comment: It still doesn't update.I tried your suggestions

Comment: Please edit the original question and put the final code you are running so that we can check it again after all the modifications

Comment: change <input  type="text" style="display: none;" value="$id" name="id"> to be <input  type="hidden" value="'.$id.'" name="id">

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I really appriciate you answer! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the last part of your code. Your form method is POST and yet you're trying to get id via GET. You can't do that, and you can't get the id from the input like this.

This is what you should do:

```
if($query_row['approval']==0){
  echo "this user is waiting for you approval";
echo $firstname.'   '.$lastname.'  has this cv:'.$cv.'<br />
Do you want to approve his account?
<form action="admin.php" method="post">
<input  type="hidden" value="$id" name="id">
<input  type="submit" value="yes" name="yes">
</form>
<br/>';
}

}
mysql_close($database);
?>
```

And on the line

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

It should turn into

```
 $id = intval($_POST['id']);
```

Comment: @phiterFernandez I tried this  but still the same the buttons are displayed but aren't functional so the `approval ` field isn;t updated!

Comment: Ah you didn't close the input tags, i'll update my answer

Comment: No problem with the tags but it still doesn't update